# Can I change the state for given time and then revert it back to the original state using settimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I want to get the value to true for one second, after which it will revert back to false using settimeout but stuck. Here is my code:

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState(false)
const handleClick = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        setValue(!value)
        console.log(value);
    },1000);
    console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(false);
const timeoutId = useRef(null);

const handleClick = () => {
    // clear existing timeout
    clearTimeout(timeoutId.current);
    // set the value to true
    setValue(true);
    // revert the value to false after 1s
    timeoutId.current = setTimeout(() => setValue(false), 1000);
}
```